# Multiple select statements - Single result

Tags: sql

I have a product list view  and a v1 value which is used for mapping

For example  in erp view it look like below

| `PRODUCT_ID` | `PRODUCT_NAME` | `QUANTITY` | `v1` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WOOD PALLET 120x80 | 10 | 25 |
| 2 | WOOD PALLET 200x80 | 5 | 25 |
| 25 | RAW MATERIAL WOOD | 100 | 25 |

in postgres we have for it 2 tables

Table: PRODUCTS

| `PRODUCT_ID` | `PRODUCT_NAME` | `QUANTITY` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WOOD PALLET 120x80 | 10 |
| 2 | WOOD PALLET 200x80 | 5 |
| 25 | RAW MATERIAL WOOD | 100 |

Table: PRODUCTS_MAPPING

| `PRODUCT_ID` | `MAPPING_KEY` |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 25 | 25 |

Now I need a query that will give only one row result which is total of quantity grouped by v1 so result should be 115

I try below query

```sql
(
    SELECT
        SUM( pr.quantity )
    FROM
        products AS pr 
    WHERE
        pr.product_id = ( SELECT map.product_id FROM products_mapping AS map WHERE mapping_key = v1 )
)
```

My problem is that after `WHERE` there is second `SELECT` statement which is giving multiple results. I need a statement which will do below calculation:

1. Check v1 value (25)
2. Go to product mapping table. Find 3 entry for mapping key 25.
3. Go to Product table and sum quantity for `products_id 1,2,3` and give result `10+5+100 = 115`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood properly you only want a single result but you haven't put a group by clause in your sentence.

```
SELECT  sum(pr.quantity) FROM products pr JOIN products_mapping map 
on pr.product_id=map.product_id  WHERE 
mapping_key=v1 group by map.mapping_key
```

I have rewritten your statement using joins.